# Auto-Open PPT, DOCX, Etc in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

I like how in chrome you can open .PDF files with the built in PDF reader (I believe it uses the adobe reader framework).

Is there a way to have chrome open MS office files in google drive by default? Without having to open the file on my computer.

You can do this with gmail by clicking "View" but I don't see that on other websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on an Office file there should be an `Open` option at the bottom. Click on the arrow and choose `Google Drive Viewer`. Is this what you mean?

EDIT: Download this plugin for Chrome: [Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn/related?hl=en). I've just tried it and it works with a large number of file types. The option will be in your context menu.

Comment: I don't see that option: http://i.imgur.com/3xTpWD1.png

Comment: I was under the impression you were in Google Drive when clicking on the files?

Comment: No, a document on any given webpage. One where I would click a "Click here to download microsoft word file"

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant from within Google Drive. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I've edited my answer. There's a plugin by Google that give you the functionality you want.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. I'll look into it later tonight

Comment: Right-click on the file you want to open and the option will be in your context menu. It's working fine for me.